# how can i test an api POST call with multiple input

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, api, loops

I want to perform a POST call with several different inputs.
So everytime i give a url to create a journal with a name(id) , 
** check if response status is 201 
** check if reposne.body.id is the journal id requested to create
** check if response.body.type is journal type that is requested to create.

```
test.only('Getting a list of requested type of journals', async () => {
                const commonUrl = '/1/tenant/1/administration/99998/journal';
                for (const jornalName of [
                    { value: 'VRK3' },
                    { value: 'INK3' },
                    { value: 'CASH' },
                    { value: 'MEM1' },
                    { value: 'BNK1' },
                ]) {
                    const response = await utils.performRequest(
                        request
                            .put(utils.api(commonUrl + jornalName.value))
                            .set(authHeader)
                            .send([
                                {
                                    description: 'test',
                                    type: 'sales',
                                    ledger_account_id: 60,
                                },
                                {
                                    description: 'test',
                                    type: 'purchase',
                                    ledger_account_id: 120,
                                },
                                {
                                    description: 'test',
                                    type: 'cash',
                                    ledger_account_id: 830,
                                },
                                {
                                    description: 'test',
                                    type: 'general',
                                    ledger_account_id: 170,
                                },
                                {
                                    description: 'test',
                                    type: 'bank',
                                    ledger_account_id: 625,
                                },
                            ]),
                    );
                    if (expect(response.status).toEqual(201)) {
                        console.log(
                            `Journal ${jornalName.value} created with automatic range assignment`,
                        );
                    }

                    expect(response.body.id).toBe(`${jornalName.value}`);
                    expect(response.body.type).toBe([
                        'sales',
                        'purchase',
                        'cash',
                        'general',
                        'bank',
                    ]);
                  }
            });
```